# VB.net lag across different machines

Tags: vb.net, timer, lag

I wrote a small little key inventory program. Basically it uses an INI file to know what keys we have and which ones are signed out, to whom, by whom, etc.  It is run on up to 4 computers all in the same room and accesses the ini file on our local server.

When I sign a key out or in, it shows the change instantly.  If I run two instances of the same program on the same machine, again, it's instant.

When I sign out a key on machine A and a co-worker is running the same program on machine B, C or D, the change in what is signed out doesn't show up for 4-10 seconds.

The way the program checks for updates is by using IO.File.Getlastwritetime on loading (saving it to a label with visible = false) and then every time the timer goes (every second) it compares the files "getlastwritetime" to the label.  If they are different, then it updates, if they are the same, it does nothing.

Any idea where I should start looking for this lag?  Could it be a server problem?

Here is the code for Timer1.tick, I am using the read/write ini codes from http://deepvbnet.blogspot.in/2008/07/how-to-read-from-ini-file.html

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim TimeCheck As String = IO.File.GetLastWriteTime("G:/BFAS/DPS/Comm Center/TEST/keys.ini")
    If TimeCheck <> Label5.Text Then
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        ComboBox1.Items.Clear()

        str1 = "NumOfKeys"
        Call readIniFile()

        Dim OneTime As String = strdata.ToString
        Dim numberofkeys As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(OneTime)

        For i = 1 To numberofkeys
            str1 = "Key" & i & "Out"
            Call readIniFile()
            Dim isKeyOut As String = strdata.ToString
            If isKeyOut = "True" Then
                str1 = "Key" & i & "Name"
                Call readIniFile()
                Dim KeyName As String = strdata.ToString

                str1 = "Key" & i & "Unit"
                Call readIniFile()
                Dim string1 As String = strdata.ToString

                str1 = "Key" & i & "Rent"
                Call readIniFile()
                Dim string2 As String = strdata.ToString

                str1 = "Key" & i & "User"
                Call readIniFile()
                Dim string3 As String = strdata.ToString

                str1 = "Key" & i & "Date"
                Call readIniFile()
                Dim string4 As String = strdata.ToString

                str1 = "Key" & i & "Time"
                Call readIniFile()
                Dim string5 As String = strdata.ToString

                ListBox1.Items.Add(LSet(KeyName, 20) + " - " + string1 + " - " + string2 + " - " + string3 + " - " + string4 + " - " + string5)
            ElseIf isKeyOut = "False" Then
                str1 = "Key" & i & "Name"
                Call readIniFile()
                Dim thisKeysName As String = strdata.ToString
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(thisKeysName)
            End If

        Next
        Dim FileTime As String = IO.File.GetLastWriteTime("G:/BFAS/DPS/Comm Center/TEST/keys.ini")
        Label5.Text = FileTime
    End If


    Dim escortTime As String = IO.Directory.GetLastWriteTime("G:/BFAS/DPS/Comm Center/TEST/Escort")
    If escortTime <> Label7.Text Then
        ListBox2.Items.Clear()
        For Each foundfile In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("G:/BFAS/DPS/Comm Center/TEST/Escort/")
            If foundfile = "G:/BFAS/DPS/Comm Center/TEST/Escorthistory.txt" Then
                'do nothing
            Else
                Dim Infomation As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(foundfile)
                ListBox2.Items.Add(Infomation)
            End If
        Next

        Label7.Text = IO.Directory.GetLastWriteTime("G:/BFAS/DPS/Comm Center/TEST/Escort")
    End If

    Dim alarmtime As String = IO.Directory.GetLastWriteTime("G:/BFAS/DPS/Comm Center/TEST/Alarms")
    If alarmtime <> Label8.Text Then
        ListBox3.Items.Clear()
        For Each foundfile In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("G:/BFAS/DPS/Comm Center/TEST/Alarms/")
            Dim Infomation As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(foundfile)
            ListBox3.Items.Add(Infomation)

        Next
        Label8.Text = IO.Directory.GetLastWriteTime("G:/BFAS/DPS/Comm Center/TEST/Alarms")
    End If



    Dim turnovertime As String = IO.File.GetLastWriteTime("G:/BFAS/DPS/Comm Center/TEST/turnover.txt")
    If Label9.Text <> turnovertime Then
        Dim newTO As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("G:/BFAS/DPS/Comm Center/TEST/turnover.txt")
        TextBox3.Text = newTO
        Label9.Text = IO.File.GetLastWriteTime("G:/BFAS/DPS/Comm Center/TEST/turnover.txt")
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Could you show the relevant part of your code? The part where you read and perform the checks?

Comment: Added Timer1.tick code

Comment: You'd better use a database stored on a server and shared with every machine. String comparisons and concatenation are really expensive, and so is the management of an INI file.

Comment: Interesting note in [GetLastWriteTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx) And by the way GetLastWriteTime returns a DateTime not a string. Perhaps they are the same but you are comparing apples with bananas. Wrong approach, use a DateTime global variable for this kind of checkings

Comment: I would suggest you stick the file on a machine other than the one running VS and step through the code to see where your slowness is. You do a lot of `GetFiles()` which will run slower on remote computers if there are a lot of files in the folder.